# Loop over 2 lists to create multiple sql cursors with 2 changing variables in each cursor

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

I need to send an SQL cursor where each cursor will update a row in the **lat** column of the table. Each cursor has to get automatically the value to update and the **id** of the row that will be updated.

I've tried using for `loop` and `zip`, which works technically, but the values are incorrect.

My code:

```
list_tu = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
ids_list = [ '7', '7', '7', '3','5', '7', '3', '2']

        def insert_tu():
            conn = connection_forward_db
            cursor = conn.cursor()        
            for tu, ids in zip(list_tu, ids_list):
                cursor.execute("UPDATE forwarder2000 SET CU = "+tu+" WHERE 
    Product_ID = "+ids+"")
        conn.commit()
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM forwarder2000", con=conn)
    print(df)

insert_tu()
```

the expected result should be `"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"` in the last column.

But I get `5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I figured out that the problem is in zip, but I don't know what other method to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your code to insert the values using a parameter like

```
 def insert_tu():
        conn = connection_forward_db
        cursor = conn.cursor()        
        for row in zip(list_tu, ids_list):
            cursor.execute("UPDATE forwarder2000 SET CU = %s WHERE Product_ID = %s",row)
    conn.commit()
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM forwarder2000", con=conn)
print(df)
```

But your code should work I think, did it end up changing the values at all in the database?

Comment: THanks! I will change the code as you mentioned. 
THe problem was in the ID column -  there were some ID numbers that were the same %), that's why I had a mess in the final result. 

But the code actually works, so thanks!